# Jenkins NUnit plugin lacks useful info

Tags: jenkins, nunit

We have implemented some integration tests using NUnit under Jenkins and have used the NUnit plugin to produce a report output. But the output is devoid of any useful info, especially error messages and console output. Are we doing something wrong?

The test uses the following, with names changed to protect the innocent.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" 
"D:\public\data\sweb\eNterpriseTesting\eNterpriseTesting.Library\bin\Debug\eNterpriseTesting.Library.dll" 
/run:eNterpriseTesting.Library.Tests.OrderTest
/xml:D:\public\data\sweb\eNterpriseTesting\eNterpriseTesting.Library\bin\Debug\TestResult.xml
```

Any Ideas other than using reportUnit?

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin)?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the NUnit plugin for Jenkins.

Comment: There will be a nunit.ouput.xml in the bin folder..You need to put that in Publish Nunit Result Section in the Jenkins Job Configuration.

Comment: Thanks Kavish but the file is not there. Am I not defining something correctly in the Nunit call?

Comment: I have the same question - did you ever find a way to solved this problem?